# RuntimeBinderException invoking a method on a generic type as dynamic

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm trying to invoke a method on a generic type (generic is also an argument to invoking method) and are hitting `RuntimeBinderException` that I don't really see how to work around.

As you can see in below example the instance returns the `MyHandler` instance (as a `dynamic`) which I expect to get invoked, but without explicit conversion to the generic type of the DTO (`as MyDto`) it will crash. And my requirement is to determine the type in runtime (as I see the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data, type)` does, until the point of invocation).

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    string dataType = typeof(MyDto).AssemblyQualifiedName;
    string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new MyDto());

    var type = Type.GetType(dataType);
    var dto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data, type);
    var handler = GetHandler();

    await handler.HandleMessageAsync(dto, CancellationToken.None); // throws the RuntimeBinderException   
    await handler.HandleMessageAsync(dto as MyDto, CancellationToken.None); // is able to invoke MyHandler.HandleMessageAsync

}

public static dynamic GetHandler()
{
    // this is simplified logic for locating a handler instance.
    return new MyHandler();
}
```

The exception thrown in the 1st invocation from example is

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'The best overloaded method match for 'ConsoleApp.MessageHandlerBase<ConsoleApp.MyDto>.HandleMessageAsync(ConsoleApp.MyDto, System.Threading.CancellationToken)' has some invalid arguments'

I don't see how the conversion can make a change to the DTO as they are the same type. So, my question is how I can succeed invoking the method completely dynamically?

This is the simplified DTO and handler service class hierarchy of the real implementation:

```
public class MyDto 
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; } = 1;
}

public interface IMessageHandler<in T> where T : class
{
    Task HandleMessageAsync(T dto, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}

public class MyHandler : IMessageHandler<MyDto>
{
    public Task HandleMessageAsync(MyDto dto, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnError called from " + this);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you calling `HandleMessageAsync(MyDto, ...)`, if you don't have `MyDto` available at runtime? Have you actually run your sample, or could it be the case that you get the failure when `MyDto` is not available, and it's fine when `MyDto` is available, regardless of the cast?

Comment: @canton7 I think that "The issue is that I do not have static type available in the runtime." was misleading. 
I've edited that part out. What I wanted to say is that I need to deserialize the type with Type specified in the runtime. (the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data, type)` part)

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] which we can run, please?

Comment: @canton7 all the code to run this is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try changing type of dto variable from object to dynamic as below -

```
dynamic dto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data, type);
```

The final code should something like this -

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    string dataType = typeof(MyDto).AssemblyQualifiedName;
    string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new MyDto());

    var type = Type.GetType(dataType);
    dynamic dto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data, type); // declare as dynamic instead of var (declaring as var would default to object type)
    var handler = GetHandler();

    await handler.HandleMessageAsync(dto, CancellationToken.None); // throws the RuntimeBinderException   
    await handler.HandleMessageAsync(dto as MyDto, CancellationToken.None); // is able to invoke MyHandler.HandleMessageAsync

}
```

Comment: That works, thanks. Do you have any explanation? This came as a surprise :)

Comment: When working with object type, you need an explicit cast while performing any operations on them, while with dynamic no cast is required. This is because .net runtime enforces additional rules while evaluating object type (e.g. you will invalid cast  compile time error when assigning object to any type), but these rules are lenient in case of dynamic (you won't get compile time error while assigning dynamic to any type , you will get runtime error if object cannot be casted). To summarize, for object explicit cast is required and for dynamic it's not.